# Как рассчитать ресурсы необходимые для стенда нагрузочного тестирования?

Tags: test-automation, нагрузочное-тестирование, jmeter

Вопросы по созданию стенда для нагрузочного/стресс теста веб портала.

Подскажите пожалуйста в каких попугаях измеряется нагрузка, количество запросов в секунду что-то еще?
Как рассчитать сколько надо ресурсов сервера (CPU, RAM) за создания нагрузки в N попугаев на тестируемую среду.
Для проведения тестирования планируется использовать JMetr и Яндекс.Танк.

Стенды заводить планируется в облаке, брать несколько нод и распараллелить с них нагрузку.

Answer (score 1):

Никак, только мерить, ибо зависит от многих факторов, например:

1. Количество [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) в тесте
2. Размер запроса/ответа
3. Время отклика системы
4. Наличие/количество [PreProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions)

Например, если вы тестируете простой эндпоинт, который возвращает пару килобайт данных - с одной JMeter ноды вы сможете запустить, например, 1000 потоков. Если тот же эндпоинт будет возвращать пару гигабайт - то 1000 потоков уже навряд ли получится, выйдет, например 100. А если этот гигабайт надо еще и распарсить чтобы вытащить оттуда интересующие данные - и того меньше.

Обычно поступают следующим образом:

1. Настраиваете мониторинг основных ресурсов машины, на которой будете гонять JMeter (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk IO и т.д.). Обычно облачные провайдеры предоставляют инструментарий для этого, например [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch), но если нет, или оно платное - можно использовать [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. Начинаете с 1 виртуального пользователя и **постепенно** увеличиваете нагрузку, в то же время смотрите на то как себя чувствует машинка: хватает ли памяти, не сильно ли загружен процессор, и т.д. Как только любая из метрик начнет превышать 85-90% - останавливайте тест и смотрите сколько виртуальных пользователей было на тот момент активно ([Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime)) и сколько запросов в секунду они отправляли ([Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/)).